# how do i write an html code that can communicate with my raspberry pi with an 7.5 inch e-paper screen?

Tags: html, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi-zero

Ive got a raspberry pi zero connected to an 7.5 inch e-paper screen.
My plan is to make an .html file/website which can upload any image alongside text to the e-paper
I want to put it on the door of the company im an intern at for when there's no one and when they're back.
this is one of the projects i've been assigned here

i have little knowledge of html, but ive got this guide to help me for most parts:
w3schools.com/html

Comment: Not something that you can do with HTML. HTML is a markup language originally to format scientific documents. With websites it is pretty much the same it still is a markup language to format text documents.

Comment: You should learn about web technologies first, like JavaScript and running Node, the question is badly formatted and there is missing underlying knowledge. A better way to ask would be not specifying HTML.